# nodejs winston - Logging with multiple arguments

Tags: node.js, winston

I was trying to use winston for logging, but I am seeing that if I want to get the data with 2  arg, then I am getting the log, but if I want to get 3 arguments, then I am not getting the data,

Ex:

```
logger = new (winston.Logger)({
transports: [
   new (winston.transports.Console)({colorize : true, timestamp:true}),
 ]
});
```

Now trying to get the log as below:

```
 1. logger.info("We got the data %s, %d", data, port);
 O/P: We got the data %s, %d  => No data and port value
 2. logger.info("We got the data, port", data, port);
 O/P: We got the data, port   => No data and port value
 3. logger.info("We got the data", data);
 ===> Getting the data correctly.
```

Can you please let me know what I was missing in 1, 2 or does winston not log the data in case 1 & 2 really?

Answer (score 13):

This is what worked for me and winston 3.2.x:

```js
const { format, createLogger, transports } = require('winston');
const jsonStringify = require('fast-safe-stringify');

const logLikeFormat = {
  transform(info) {
    const { timestamp, label, message } = info;
    const level = info[Symbol.for('level')];
    const args = info[Symbol.for('splat')];
    const strArgs = args.map(jsonStringify).join(' ');
    info[Symbol.for('message')] = `${timestamp} [${label}] ${level}: ${message} ${strArgs}`;
    return info;
  }
};

const debugFormat = {
  transform(info) {
    console.log(info);
    return info;
  }
};

const logger = createLogger({
  format: format.combine(
    // debugFormat, // uncomment to see the internal log structure
    format.timestamp(),
    format.label({ label: 'myLabel' }),
    logLikeFormat,
    // debugFormat, // uncomment to see the internal log structure
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.Console()
  ]
});


logger.info('foo', 'bar', 1, [2, 3], true, { name: 'John' });
```

which results in: `2019-07-04T21:30:08.455Z [myLabel] info: foo "bar" 1 [2,3] true {"name":"John"}`

Basically `format.combine` sets a pipeline for an `info` object. For each format function, `transform` is called and the final log message should be written to `info[Symbol.for('message')]`
hope this helps

Answer (score 12):

Since Winston API doesn't work like `console.log`, therefore a workaround would be to create a wrapper function which utilizes `util.format` in the following way:

```
const util = require('util')   

...

function log(...msg) {
  logger.info(util.format(...msg))
}
```

Then you can call the log like:
   `log('my log entry', 'foo, 'bar')`

Which will log like this: `{"message":"my log entry foo bar","level":"info"}`

Comment: I like this better as `util.format()` handles circular reference out-of-the-box

Answer (score 3):

You are assuming there is a varargs style API, but there is not. The full API is `level, msg, meta, callback`, but when you use one of the methods that is the level, then it's just `msg, meta, callback`. You need to construct a single `meta` object and pass that.

https://github.com/flatiron/winston/blob/master/lib/winston/logger.js#L115

```
//
// ### function log (level, msg, [meta], callback)
// #### @level {string} Level at which to log the message.
// #### @msg {string} Message to log
// #### @meta {Object} **Optional** Additional metadata to attach
// #### @callback {function} Continuation to respond to when complete.
// Core logging method exposed to Winston. Metadata is optional.
//
```

https://github.com/flatiron/winston#logging-with-metadata

Comment: I have added this pull request to winston to make this more clear in the docs:
https://github.com/vanthome/winston/compare/flatiron:master...patch-1?quick_pull=1

Comment: The bottom link now shows that winston does support varargs API, but treats the last argument as the "meta" object to print. Include {} as an additional argument at the end to make sure it uses the arguments before it for string interpolation: https://github.com/flatiron/winston#logging-with-metadata

Answer (score 2):

I worked around this by wrapping the winston functions, and using the wrapper. I hope there's a better solution for this by now.

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
        transports:[new (winston.transports.Console)({ json : false, timestamp : true, level : 0, colorize : true}),
                    new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: filepath, json : false, timestamp : true, level : 0, colorize: true })]
    });

// pass in function arguments object and returns string with whitespaces
function argumentsToString(v){
    // convert arguments object to real array
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(v);
    for(var k in args){
        if (typeof args[k] === "object"){
            // args[k] = JSON.stringify(args[k]);
            args[k] = util.inspect(args[k], false, null, true);
        }
    }
    var str = args.join(" ");
    return str;
}


    // wrapping the winston function to allow for multiple arguments
    var wrap = {};
    wrap.info = function () {
        logger.log.apply(logger, ["info", argumentsToString(arguments)]);
    };

    wrap.error = function () {
        logger.log.apply(logger, ["error", argumentsToString(arguments)]);
    };

    wrap.warn = function () {
        logger.log.apply(logger, ["warn", argumentsToString(arguments)]);
    };

    wrap.debug = function () {
        logger.log.apply(logger, ["debug", argumentsToString(arguments)]);
    };
```

/// then return wrap as is it was your logger.
/// and use like log.info(1,2,3,4,"foo","bar");

Answer (score 0):

**This is my logging module and it works fine for my all projects.**

```
const winston = require('winston');

module.exports = function() {
    const logger = winston.createLogger({
        format: winston.format.combine(
            winston.format.timestamp(),
            winston.format.colorize(),
            winston.format.json()           
        ),
        transports: [
          new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log' }),
        ]
      });

      if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        logger.add(new winston.transports.Console({
            format: winston.format.combine(
                winston.format.timestamp(),
                winston.format.colorize(),
                winston.format.json()               
            )
        }));
      }

    process.on('unhandledRejection', (error) =>{
        logger.error(error.stack);
    });

    process.on('uncaughtException', (error) =>{
        logger.error(error.stack);
    }); 
}
```